# How to do React - Redux connection?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I am taking a course **"React - The Complete Guide (incl Hooks, React Router, Redux)" on Udemy**. I have exactly followed the steps by Maximilian on the lecture, but getting an error:

Failed to compile.

```
(webpack)/buildin/harmony-module.js
Error: UNKNOWN: unknown error, read
```

I have posted my project on: 
https://github.com/AswinTimalsina/reactBurgerProject/tree/redux-global-state

Comment: Have you run `npm install`?

Answer (score 1):

Hello you have to first install redux

```
npm install react-redux
```

or

```
yarn add react-redux
```

then import it in your app.js like

```
import React from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'
```